# Retrieve from 2 collection firebase flutter at the same time

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I don't know how to retrieve data from both collection, what im trying to do is compare both sales, i can only retrieve data from one sales, im trying to get data from both sales and make a comparison of them but i have no idea, below is my code, i want to display another data from the collection 10.2022 Sales where the data is sales : 500, i have written where i want the data to be in the code, i hope someone can help me

```
Visibility(
  visible: gotChoice,
  child: StreamBuilder<List<showSummaryReport>>(
      stream: read('${widget.expChoice.toString()} Sales'),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Center(
            child: Text("some error occured"),
          );
        }
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          final userData = snapshot.data;
          return Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: userData!.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final service = userData[index];

                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      ListTile(
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>
                                selectedDetailReport(detail: '${service.serviceName} Sales',
                                  month: widget.expChoice.toString(),)));
                          },
                          title: Card(
                            color: 'CAF0F8'.toColor(),
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                            child: Table(
                              // border: TableBorder(bottom: BorderSide(color: '03045E'.toColor(), width: 1)),
                              children: [
                                TableRow(children: [SizedBox(height: 10,), SizedBox(height: 10,)]),
                                TableRow(
                                    children: [
                                      Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30,0,0,0),
                                        child: Text('Service Name :',style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonSemi', fontSize: 17)),
                                      ),
                                      Center(child: Text(service.serviceName.toString(),style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonSemi', fontSize: 17))),
                                    ]
                                ),
                                TableRow(children: [SizedBox(height: 10,), SizedBox(height: 10,)]),
                                TableRow(
                                    children: [
                                      Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30,0,0,0),
                                        child: Text('Current Month Sales :',style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonSemi', fontSize: 17)),
                                      ),
                                      Center(child: Text(service.sales.toString(),style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonSemi', fontSize: 17))),
                                    ]
                                ),
                                TableRow(children: [SizedBox(height: 10,), SizedBox(height: 10,)]),
                                TableRow(
                                    children: [
                                      Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30,0,0,0),
                                        child: Text('Selected Sales :',style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonSemi', fontSize: 17)),
                                      ),
                                      Center(child: Text('the data display at here',style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonSemi', fontSize: 17))),
                                    ]
                                ),
                                TableRow(children: [SizedBox(height: 10,), SizedBox(height: 10,)]),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                }),
          );
        }
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      }),
),

static Stream<List<showSummaryReport>> read(String type) {
    final serviceCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(type);
    return serviceCollection.snapshots().map((querySnapshot) =>
        querySnapshot.docs.map((e) => showSummaryReport.fromSnapshot(e)).toList());
  }
```

this is the first collection [image]

this is the second collection [image]

this is where i wan the data to be [image]

Comment: can you include a screenshot of how your firestore db looks like, and include an example of what you expect ?

Comment: sir, i have edited the question and paste some images